# Python SDK to locally hosted Kubernetes Couchbase

Tags: python, kubernetes, couchbase

in other thread I made I asked for the solution to a problem regarding connecting to Couchbase.

From then, I've experimented with other approach. Carefully following every step in Couchbase documentation, I have managed to setup a Couchbase cluster on Kubernetes.
[image]

However, I still cannot connect SDK to it. How do I run Python **outside of Kubernetes** and connect to the Couchbase instance hosted locally **on Kubernetes cluster**? Specifically, what is the "connection_string" in the standard code I post below:

```py
    connection_string = "<WHAT TO PUT THERE?>"
    cluster = Cluster.connect(connection_string,
                              ClusterOptions(PasswordAuthenticator(os.getenv("LOGIN"), os.getenv("PASSWORD"))))
    bucket = cluster.bucket('travel-sample')
    coll = bucket.default_collection()
    query_iter = cluster.query("SELECT * FROM `travel-sample` LIMIT 100")
    for r in query_iter.rows():
        print(f"Found row: {r}")
```

Comment: looking at the [docs](https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-python-client/couchbase_api/couchbase_core.html#couchbase.cluster.Cluster.connect/) its just the url of the couchbase deployment using the `couchbase` scheme. Probably the url of the k8s service or deployment couchbase is deployed with. Make sure that the networking in your k8s is set up to allow that type of traffic to flow in an out.